# runscript with integer input in python

Tags: python

I want to run from a terminal a python code that required an integer input in my code such as

> python code.py 4

I saw that the input() function works when I do

> python code.py

> 4

but I have a script that run many times the same code with different integers so I would like to use something where I could run my code at the same time as I feed the integer.

Any idea how ?

Many thanks,
Ele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `sys` import to read from the `sys.argv` list to get commandline arguments.

from [tutorialspoint documentation on cmd arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

```py
import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

in your case :

```py
import sys

value = sys.argv[1] #argv[0] is the name of the script
```